# Broke Rails application by generating a scaffold with name Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Teaching myself Rails and came across the following problem that I can't seem to find any information about.

I seem to have broken my Rails application by generating a scaffold named "Controller". The application keeps track of hardware controllers, so I wanted to create a scaffold and database to hold all the information on the hardware controllers that are stored.

I ran the following:

```
rails generate scaffold Controller manufacturer:references model:string controller_type:references
```

I ran `rake db:migrate` and reloaded the root path of the application website (which does not use Controller, but a couple other models that were previously working fine) and get the following error page:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"controllers"} Try
>   running rake routes for more information on available routes.

I ran `rails destroy Controller` and all the associated folders and files are gone, but I still receive the error page.

Did I somehow accidentally overwrite a built-in controller name? Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Comment: Post route.rb and `rake routes`. You probably edited routes.rb by accident.

Comment: might need to restart server after using destory?

Comment: This happened to me and after hours of pulling my hair out I restarted the server and it fixed it. It's because you (I) created a scaffold with the name of Controller which of course is not right. @JustinD that just reported the routes as correct, even though the app didn't think so.

Answer (score 0):

That command probably added this line to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
 resources :controllers
```

Just remove that line, restart your server* and then try again.

---

* You shouldn't need to restart as the routes are reloaded per-request, but sometimes weird things happen.

Answer (score -1):

you can set your root route in `[rails]/config/routes.rb`

`root :to => 'welcome#index'`

`welcome = controller name`